# Validate form added to DOM with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, dom

Quick question: How can I  use good, old [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate a form which gets added to the DOM (via Ajax) after the page has loaded?

`$("form#superForm").validate(options);` doesn't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("form#superForm").validate(options);` does work. It's just that you're trying to attach it before the content (`form#superForm`) is loaded.

If you want it to work  properly, you'll have to attach it after you've loaded it in. So, for example:

```
$('#somediv').load('path/to/ajax/that/returns/form#superForm', function() {
    $("form#superForm").validate(options);
});
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.  I've tried it as you suggest but not having any success.  I prefer to use the options with rules: and messages: but they don't work in this scenario.  If I annotate the <input> with class="required" it'll turn red but no message. I've tried it with and without the "required".  Without the class nothing happens.

Comment: Can you put some of your code up on http://jsFiddle.net, so that I can see what you're trying to do? Be terse. Only post the relative information...

Answer (score 0):

> $("form#superForm").validate(options); doesn't work...

It will work, you only have to call it once the form is added to the DOM which is in the success callback of your AJAX call. I suppose that you are calling it in `document.ready` when the form doesn't exist yet in the DOM.

For example:

```
$(function() {
    // when some button is clicked we load the form:
    $('.button').click(function() {
        // we send an AJAX request to load the form
        $.post('/somescript', function(result) {
            // the AJAX request succeeds and we inject the result into the DOM:
            $('#result').html(result);

            // now we can attach the validator:
            $('#superForm').validate(options);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```